# How to read this JSON with PHP?

Tags: php, json

I am getting this JSON from an API call:

```
{"region.regions":[{"region":[{"name":"Trebbin","geoCodeId":1276004017004,"amount":0}]}]}
```

It is contained in a variable called `$data`. When I debug, it tells me that `region.regions` is an array, but I cant use it as such.

This is how I read the data into my var:

```
$data = json_decode($jsonStringFromApiCall, true);
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: `$data = json_decode($jsonStringFromApiCall, true);` you can access `"region.regions` as `$data['"region.regions']`

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help you..

```
$json = '{"region.regions":[{"region":[{"name":"Trebbin","geoCodeId":1276004017004,"amount":0}]}]}';
$data =  json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($data['region.regions'] as $region)
{
    foreach($region['region'] as $geo)
{
    echo "Name - ".$geo['name']."<br>";
    echo "Geo Code - ".$geo['geoCodeId']."<br>";
    echo "Amount - ".$geo['amount']."<br>";

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data='{"region.regions":[{"region":[{"name":"Trebbin","geoCodeId":1276004017004,"amount":0}]}]}';
$json=json_decode( $data, true );

$name=$json['region.regions'][0]['region'][0]['name'];
$geocode=$json['region.regions'][0]['region'][0]['geoCodeId'];
$amount=$json['region.regions'][0]['region'][0]['amount'];;

echo $name, ' ', $geocode,' ', $amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode($jsonStringFromApiCall, true);
```

you can now get data using `$data['region.regions']`